Lombok Plugin: Gradle error generateEffectiveLombokConfig uses task without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency
In our Java Spring project we use Lombok extensively and use the lombok gradle plugin.
We also do code generation with the Open API plugin.
When I upgrade from Lombok 8.6 to 8.10 (with no other changes) I now get this error from Gradle.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':entity-client:generateEffectiveLombokConfig' (type 'LombokConfig').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/fkelly/dev/platform2-entity/entity-client/build/openapi-source/src/main/java'.

    Reason: Task ':entity-client:generateEffectiveLombokConfig' uses this output of task ':entity-client:generateClientCode' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':entity-client:generateClientCode' as an input of ':entity-client:generateEffectiveLombokConfig'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':entity-client:generateClientCode' from ':entity-client:generateEffectiveLombokConfig' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':entity-client:generateClientCode' from ':entity-client:generateEffectiveLombokConfig' using Task#mustRunAfter.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

How generateEffectiveLombokConfig is defined?

Share your build.gradle please.

@talex generateEffectiveLombokConfig is provided by the lombok plugin itself - see https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/main/lombok-plugin/src/main/java/io/freefair/gradle/plugins/lombok/internal/ConfigUtil.java#L43-L51

@AnishB. sorry my build.gradle is quite large and I don't have a smaller reproducible test case yet. That said, I have not made any changes in my gradle files - nor did I update Gradle - so I believe that means it must be something that changed in the lombok plugin itself.

I found a work-around after some Gradle googling but I'm not happy with it.
// Due to Gradle dependency error when upgrading from Lombok 8.6 to 8.10
// Based on solution https://discuss.gradle.org/t/implicit-dependency-among-tasks-but-the-tasks-do-not-exist/46127
tasks.configureEach {
    if (name == "generateEffectiveLombokConfig") {
        mustRunAfter(tasks.generateClientCode)
    }
}

Is there an alternative? Perhaps something more concise?

See https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/1193

Thank you @Toofy

Perhaps tasks.withType(LombokConfig).configureEach { mustRunAfter(tasks.generateClientCode) } would be simpler

I think the bug fix in the gradle plugin is simplest of all ;-)
